# when would I say "I'm having a hard time believing"?

Tags: word-usage

This is a question in a practice.

[image]

I guess this is the answer

> I'm having a hard time believing as he says about Jenny.

My actual question is, what the situation could be when a speaker would say that?

Is the following situation reasonable?

Christopher just told Ronald something about Jenny, and Ronald **is telling** me what he got from Christopher. That's why Ronald uses "**I'm having**".

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the correct answer in your test is:

> what he said about Jenny

In your context and according to the Cambridge Dictionary, the meaning of [have](https://www.lexico.com/definition/have) is:

> 2 **Experience**; undergo.
>
> *‘I went to a few parties and had a good time’
> ‘**I was having** difficulty
>   in keeping awake’*

Applying that meaning to your context, Ronald is **finding hard to believe** what Christopher said about Jenny, Ronald thinks that Christopher **may be lying**. He is **incredulous**, he is **experiencing** incredulity.

Comment: Thank you. Something like, Ronald is saying "I am not wanting to believe that", right?

Comment: He is not saying anything about WANTING or not to believe. The story told by Christopher seems difficult to believe. Usually Jennifer wouldn't do such things. Ronald is not talking about his feelings in relation with the story (want or not, be sad or not about that, ...)